overlaying graphs in subfigure
Why do the graphs overlap each other? How to fix this? And there is also a space at the top, but there is no corresponding command in my code
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\node[label={[orange] above: $v_x>0$}] at (axis cs:5,5){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\node[label={[orange] above: $v_x>0$}] at (axis cs:5,5){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\node[label={[orange] above: $v_x>0$}] at (axis cs:5,5){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}


\end{figure}


\end{document}



If your foot doesn't fit in the shoe, either the shoe is too small, or your foot is too big. There are two ways to fix it... get a bigger shoe or shrink your feet. :) You have something similar going on here. Your subfigures (shoes) are set to have a fixed width of 0.3\textwidth. You graphs (feet) on the other hand, are too big. TeX puts them in the subfigure box, but with overlap (you'll notice warnings in your .log speaking of an "overfull \hbox"). So, either increase the width of the subfigure (get a bigger shoe), or reduce your graphs (the feet).

Your diagrams width are far to wide than width of spaces reserved for them by subfigure environment. Consequently diagrams in them protrude their right borders.
A remedy for your problem can be add the following lines to images common specification
    width=0.8\linewidth,   scale only axis,

and from it remove options
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,

After this you will get:

(red lines indicate page layout)
Addendum:
Of course,  you have another possibility: insert subfigures one below other and accordingly increase subfigure width:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}

    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\node[label={[orange] above: $v_x>0$}] at (axis cs:5,5){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\node[label={[orange] above: $v_x>0$}] at (axis cs:5,5){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\node[label={[orange] above: $v_x>0$}] at (axis cs:5,5){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


However, it seems that this solution was not your intention. Anyway, from it is should be clear to see, why your try to have images in one line was failed.
